# layout with grid:how to put box1 in row 1 column 2 and box2 in row 2 column 2?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-grid

What I get the layout is as below:

[image]

What I expect is:
put `box1` in `row 1` `column 2` and `box2` in `row2` `column 2`.

Why can't put the content in `box1` and `box2` into grid of `row 1` `column 2` and grid of `row 2` `column 2`?

How to fix my css?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.5em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.box1 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="prose1">
    <h1>Introduction</h1>
    <p>100 characters created by lorem with emmt-vim.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="box1">
      <h2 class="box-header">Actions</h2>
      <ul class="box-menu">
        <li><a href="">Do a thing</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Register your bad self</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hold the phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      <h2 class="box-header">Related Stuff</h2>
      <ul class="box-menu">
        <li><a href="">Just a link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prose2">
    <h2>Additional Information</h2>
    xxxx
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To position an item on the grid, it needs to be the child of an element with `display: grid`. The boxes in your layout are children of `.sidebar`, so using grid positioning will have no effect. I believe there is a property called `subgrid` which is being added to the grid specs soon, and will function as you need.

Comment: why don't you use `flex` and `order` or change the html structure. I'm just trying to understand the point behind it

Answer (score 0):

The container is the grid in your layout, and you can position direct child items, and `box1` and `box2` are nested inside of sidebar. So normally from container you can position `porse1`, `sidebar` and `porse2`, but you can treat the sidebar child items as direct child items of the container using the `contents` display value.

So one Solution is to use the `contents` display value:

```
.sidebar {
    display: contents;
}
```

But be aware of [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

Another Solution is to make your sidebar a grid too and layout the child items `box1` and `box2` as you want, example:

```
html,
body {
  height: 1200px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1.5em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.sidebar {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.5em;
    grid-row: 1/-1;
    grid-column: 2;
}

.box1 {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.box2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `subgrid` is not deprecated, it's postponed to the CSS Grid Level 2 spec (which is in early draft stage yet — https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-2/#subgrids). Besides this, I agree with your answer!